# Is it possible to add an edit box or combo box to CommandBar["Text"] in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, office-addins

I'm trying to add an edit box or combo box to one of the context menus when my Word add-in loads. But I haven't succeeded, and I don't get any errors, the edit/combo box just don't show up.

```
this.Application.CommandBars["Text"].Reset();

// add a menu to the context menu
CommandBarPopup subMenu = (CommandBarPopup)this.Application.CommandBars["Text"].Controls
  .Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, missing, missing, 1, true);

subMenu.Caption = "My menu";

// add combo box to the newly created menu
CommandBarComboBox ctrl = (CommandBarComboBox)subMenu.Controls
  .Add(MsoControlType.msoControlComboBox, missing, missing, 1, true);

ctrl.Caption = "Bleh";
ctrl.Text = "Blah";
ctrl.AddItem("Hai", 1);
ctrl.AddItem("Hoi", 2);
ctrl.DropDownLines = 3;
ctrl.DropDownWidth = 75;
ctrl.ListIndex = 0;
ctrl.Visible = true;
```

The above code adds a menu to the right-click context menu in Word, called "My menu" and then I try to add a combo box to that menu, it doesn't show. The code is in my add-ins startup function.

Does anyone have any experience in this? is it even possible? or am I just doing something totaly wrong?

### UPDATE

I guess there is some documentation about this out there somewhere. But I just can't seem to find it. This is the documentation that I've found:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa190799(v=office.10).aspx
and from reading that, I get the impression that is should be possible to add CommandBarPopup, CommandBarComboBox and CommandBarButton.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't place any "edit" control in a menu, you can only place them in a toolbar. Menus can contain spacers or MenuCommandButtons, or submenus, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I suspect you are correct, but it would be nice to get hold of some documentation on this. I haven't found any, but I'm sure it exist somewhere. Do you know where?